# Child Process Debugger Not Working

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I just installed the [Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/).
The reason my project needs this is that I want to Unit Test a native browser extension host. So in this case, the parent process is VC++'s Native Unit Test Framework and the child process is, say, "com.my-website.exe".

Steps I follow:

1. UnitTestProject -> Debug -> Other Debug Targets -> Child Process Debugging Settings... -> Add a row: {enabled, Process Name = com.my-website.exe, Action = Attach Debugger, Debugger Type = Native}
2. Set a breakpoint in com.my-website.cpp (The child is in the same solution as the parent)
3. Run the parent in Debug mode and watch the child breakpoint not being hit in despair.

Comment: My Unit Test project's DLL and the child exe are not in the same directory, i.e. target directories for the two projects are not the same. Can this be part of the problem?